# I have object but cannot save all item from this object first object only can saved

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have object but cannot save all item from this object first object only can saved.

1interface:

```js
export interface PhotoToCreate {
 
     albumName: string;
   albumTitle: string;
   ImageNameO : string;
 imageNameT : string;
  



}
```

2Component

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { PhotoToCreate } from '../_Classes/photo-to-create.model';
import { PhotoModule } from '../_Classes/photo-module.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
@Component({
  selector: 'app-alerts',
  templateUrl: './alerts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./alerts.component.scss']
})
export class AlertsComponent implements OnInit {

  public isCreate: boolean;
  public albumName: string;
  public albumTitle: string;
  
  public photo: PhotoToCreate;
  public photos: PhotoModule[] = [];
    public response:{dbpathsasstring: ''}

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {   
   this.isCreate = true;
  }
  
 

  public spliturl = (serverss: string)=>{
   if (serverss.includes(","))
    {
    for(let i = 0;serverss.length;i++ ){
      
     console.log(i)
      var serpatharr=serverss.split(',');
      serverss=serpatharr[i];
    }
    return serverss
     }
  }
 
  public onCreate = () => {
    this.photo  = {
      albumName: this.albumName,
      albumTitle: this.albumTitle,
      ImageNameO : this.spliturl(this.response.dbpathsasstring)
  ,  
   imageNameT : this.spliturl(this.response.dbpathsasstring)
      
    } 
 
   this.http.post('https://localhost:44318/api/PhotosAlbums', this.photo)
    .subscribe(res => {
      // debugger;
       this.getUsers();
     this.isCreate = false;
    });
  }

  private getUsers = () => {
    this.http.get('https://localhost:44318/api/PhotosAlbums')
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.photos = res as PhotoModule[];
    });
  }

 public returnToCreate = () => {
   this.isCreate = true;
 }

  public uploadFinished = (event) => {
    this.response = event;
  }

  public createImgPath = (serverPath: string) => {
    if(serverPath.includes(","))
    {
    var serverPathArr = serverPath.split(',');
    serverPath = serverPathArr[0];
    }
    return `https://localhost:44318/${serverPath}`;
    }
    

}
```

html template

```html
<article class="container container-fluid">
  <section class="create" *ngIf="isCreate">
    <h1>Create User</h1>
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="albumName" name="albumName" placeholder="Enter your name" [(ngModel)]="albumName">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="address">Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="albumTitle" name="albumTitle" placeholder="Enter your address" [(ngModel)]="albumTitle">
      </div>
      <app-upload (onUploadFinished)="uploadFinished($event)"></app-upload>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="offset-md-5 col-md-2">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onCreate()">Create </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </section>

  <section class="users" *ngIf="!isCreate">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Image</th>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Address</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let photo of photos">
          <td><img [src]="createImgPath(photo.ImageNameO)" alt="profile picture" style="width:60px; height:60px;"></td>
          <td>{{photo.albumName}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.albumTitle}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="offset-md-10 col-md-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="returnToCreate()">New User</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</article>
```

path from api return 
**Resources\Images\c7ef86f6-a032-4124-9327-142f0b1e99371.png,Resources\Images\4801b60c-7d82-4e51-aab2-db2da0f9647c2.png**
**Update**

this function saved first image

```js
public spliturl = (serverss: string)=>{
   if (serverss.includes(","))
    {
      
      var serpatharr=serverss.split(',');
      serverss=serpatharr[0];
    }
    return serverss
     }
```

The path is stored in both fields
 Resources\Images\c7ef86f6-a032-4124-9327-142f0b1e99371.png,Resources\Images\4801b60c-7d82-4e51-aab2-db2da0f9647c2.png

But using this method to split path

saved first image in ImageNameO =Resources\Images\c7ef86f6-a032-4124-9327-142f0b1e99371.png

In second filed cannot save path imageNameT   =Resources\Images\4801b60c-7d82-4e51-aab2-db2da0f9647c2.png
saved null

how can saved 
image
say
ImageNameO =Resources\Images\c7ef86f6-a032-4124-9327-142f0b1e99371.png

ImageNameT = Resources\Images\4801b60c-7d82-4e51-aab2-db2da0f9647c2.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **First thing**, you have to check `spliturl` function.

**After you checked the `spliturl` is working well**, then :

> If your `spliturl` function is returning **string**, then it should be working fine.

Meanwhile :

> If your `spliturl` function is returning **Array of String**,
>
> then you should change your `PhotoToCreate` interface :

```
export interface PhotoToCreate {
  albumName: string;
  albumTitle: string;
  ImageNameO: Array<string>;
  imageNameT: Array<string>;
}
```

## [UPDATE]

Based on the comments, your question is not clear enough.

So, the idea is, you have this `onCreate` function

```
onCreate = () => {
  this.photo  = {
  albumName: this.albumName,
  albumTitle: this.albumTitle,
  ImageNameO: this.spliturl(this.response.dbpathsasstring),  
  imageNameT: this.spliturl(this.response.dbpathsasstring)
}
```

and the value of `this.response.dbpathsasstring` is :

```
this.response.dbpathsasstring = 'Resources\Images\c7ef86f6-a032-4124-9327-142f0b1e99371.png,Resources\Images\4801b60c-7d82-4e51-aab2-db2da0f9647c2.png'
```

Then you want :

> 1. `ImageNameO` value become `'Resources\Images\c7ef86f6-a032-4124-9327-142f0b1e99371.png'`
> 2. `imageNameT` value become `'Resources\Images\4801b60c-7d82-4e51-aab2-db2da0f9647c2.png'`

Now, what you need to check is your `spliturl` function.

Your current `spliturl` function :

```
public spliturl = (serverss: string) => {
  if (serverss.includes(",")) {
    for(let i = 0; serverss.length; i++){
      console.log(i)
      var serpatharr=serverss.split(',');
      serverss=serpatharr[i];    ---> Explanation 1
    }
    return serverss
  }
}

/***
** Explanation 1
**
**   // First loop :
**      value of serverss = 'Resources\Images\c7ef86f6-a032-4124-9327-142f0b1e99371.png,Resources\Images\4801b60c-7d82-4e51-aab2-db2da0f9647c2.png'
**      Then value of serpatharr = ['Resources\Images\c7ef86f6-a032-4124-9327-142f0b1e99371.png', 'Resources\Images\4801b60c-7d82-4e51-aab2-db2da0f9647c2.png']
**      Then do serverss=serpatharr[i]
**      You are replacing the value of serverss = 'Resources\Images\c7ef86f6-a032-4124-9327-142f0b1e99371.png'
**      Meaning, your serverss value is only containing one image now.
**
**   // Second loop :
**      value of serverss = 'Resources\Images\c7ef86f6-a032-4124-9327-142f0b1e99371.png'
**      Then you will never get your second image (Resources\Images\4801b60c-7d82-4e51-aab2-db2da0f9647c2.png)
**/
```

### [Fixing] based on the explanation above

So you can simply change your `spliturl` function

```
spliturl = (serverss, index) => {
  if (serverss.includes(",")) {
    const serpatharr = serverss.split(',');
    serverss = serpatharr[index];
    
    return serpatharr[index];
  }

  return serverss; // Remove this line if you dont want to return anything
}
```

and update your `onCreate` function :

```
onCreate = () => {
  this.photo  = {
  albumName: this.albumName,
  albumTitle: this.albumTitle,
  ImageNameO: this.spliturl(this.response.dbpathsasstring, 0),  
  imageNameT: this.spliturl(this.response.dbpathsasstring, 1)
}
```

Comment: I receive the result from
api
Here
    public response:{dbpathsasstring: ''}

Then I send it to the function
spliturl

Comment: Please see the problem again
You update them to be clearer

Comment: Hi @Bishoe, so **Resources\Images\c7ef86f6-a032-4124-9327-142f0b1e99371.png,Resources\Images\4801b60c-7d82-4e51-aab2-db2da0f9647c2.png** will be sent to `spliturl` function, and it will return first object only. But the thing you want is saving that 2 image in object? is that what you mean?

Comment: And the first image (**Resources\Images\c7ef86f6-a032-4124-9327-142f0b1e99371.png**, you want it to be saved in `ImageNameO` , and the second image (**Resources\Images\4801b60c-7d82-4e51-aab2-db2da0f9647c2.png**), you want it to be saved in `imageNameT`?

Comment: Yes @sherly febrianti

Comment: First, I apologize for not clearly explaining the problem

Secondly thank you now working successfully as required Thank you for your time and help me have a happy day

Comment: @Bishoe nice if it works, thank you. If it really helps you, please mark as answer and vote up. ***Cheers**